# Is asking about publishing in bioinformatics on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have [a question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/bioinformatics-flowchart-for-materials-and-methods) about how to present bioinformatics methods for publishing in a paper. I tried asking it on Academia, but it was off topic there. Would it fit here?

More generally, would questions about the field of bioinformatics be appropriate here? Or is it just for questions about problems in bioinformatics?

Comment: Was it really off topic on academia? That seems strange, did they give a reason? Was it just opinion based?

Comment: @terdon apparently it was too much about research and not studies, which didn't suit them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to venture out on a limb and say that this is on-topic. Norms, styles, and conventions for communication and publication vary widely by discipline, so in my opinion the best place to ask questions about publishing bioinformatics methods is a bioinformatics-focused forum.

In any case, this community has been pretty inclusive of mostly-programming questions or mostly-stats questions that are couched in bioinformatics language/examples. So in general it seems natural we'd do the same for mostly-publishing questions about bioinformatics methods.